# How i can start build Jwplayer plugins (Addons)?

Tags: jwplayer

I want to know everything about JWplayer , What programming languages ​​to be used for the construction of these Plugins , Is there any sites help me to start Developing on jwplayer
i wish someone help , thanks

Comment: Last I checked JWPlayer is a HTML5 video player, not a plugin.

Comment: @Havenard , yes but they support plugins check this site http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/

Comment: Well the answer is implicit, JWPlayer is HTML5 and JavaScript, therefore the plugins are also made in those languages. Aparently theres a backward compatibility version made in Flash for old browsers, so there must be a version of the plugin made in this too. Just download one from this site and see how it works.

Comment: thanks @Havenard , can you help me found plugin to put Text Overlay on the player ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build plugins for the JW Player, we have an SDK for that.

https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdks/tree/master/jw6-plugin-sdk